ROS2 Rqt_reconfigure hide params, make param groups
i am currently working on ROS2 port from ROS1. Now i am declaring parameters for manipulating a pointcloud. I want to use rqt_reconfigure, but the problem is, that there are shown all parameters from the node and some of these parameters are only for launch file to configure them at the startup. My question is, is there away to hide the parameters in rqt_reconfigure i dont want to see, or is there any other way? I just want to show in rqt_reconfigure 6 parameters, pitch, roll, yaw, x_mm,y_mm and z_mm. I made two screenshots one is from ROS1(upper screen) the other from ROS2(lower screen). The ROS1 screen shows how it should be, and the ROS2 screen shows how it is. The second question is how to make groups (Rotation and Translation) in rqt_reconfigure, like on the ros1 screen. Thank you in advance.
This is my ros2 code:
declare_float_parameter("roll", 0.0, -180.0, 180.0, "", node);

void declare_float_parameter(
        const std::string & param_name,
        double default_value,
        double min_value,
        double max_value,
        const std::string & description,
        std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> node)
    {
        auto parameter_descriptor = rcl_interfaces::msg::ParameterDescriptor();
        parameter_descriptor.type = rcl_interfaces::msg::ParameterType::PARAMETER_DOUBLE;
        parameter_descriptor.description = description;

        rcl_interfaces::msg::FloatingPointRange float_range;
        float_range.set__from_value(min_value);
        float_range.set__to_value(max_value);
        float_range.set__step(0.0); // Step value is optional for floating point range

        parameter_descriptor.floating_point_range = {float_range};

        node->declare_parameter(param_name, rclcpp::ParameterValue(default_value), parameter_descriptor);
    }



